# Array of char* should end at '\0' or "\0"?

Tags: c, pointers, null

Lets say we have an array of char pointers

```
char* array[] = { "abc", "def" };
```

Now what should be put in the end ?

```
char* array[] = { "abc", "def", '\0' };
```

or

```
char* array[] = { "abc", "def", "\0" };
```

Though, both works. We only have to put the condition to check the end accordingly

like

```
array[ index ] != '\0';
```

or

```
array[ index ] != "\0";
```

My question is which one is the better way? Which is used by most programmers?

**Edit**

Most answers say that NULL is better than '\0' and "\0".
But I always thought that

NULL is same as '\0' which is same as 0x0 or 0

Is it wrong?

Comment: Regarding the edit, In C NULL is a pointer (usually defined (void*)0. '\0' is a character constant. So when using a character constant where a pointer is expected, and implicit conversion occurs. As it happens conversion of any integer zero results in a NULL pointer, but it does not make it clear that you intended a pointer. It is better simply to use a literal constant integer zero IMO. As it happens in C++ this is the preferred approach in any case, but in C++ the NULL macro is defined that way also (take a look in your compiler's standard header files).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would end it with `NULL`. Why? Because you can't do either of these:

```
array[index] == '\0'
array[index] == "\0"
```

The first one is comparing a `char *` to a `char`, which is *not* what you want. You would have to do this:

```
array[index][0] == '\0'
```

The second one doesn't even work. You're comparing a `char *` to a `char *`, yes, but this comparison is meaningless. It passes if the two pointers point to the same piece of memory. You can't use `==` to compare two strings, you have to use the `strcmp()` function, because C has no built-in support for strings outside of a few (and I mean few) syntactic niceties. Whereas the following:

```
array[index] == NULL
```

Works just fine and conveys your point.

Comment: Actually, the `char*` comparison probably worked for the OP, since the compiler unified the two identical string literals. I agree that the comparison is meaningless, in principle.

Comment: I know it probably worked, but it is by no means guaranteed to work, and should never be relied upon, and is therefore meaningless. If it works, it works because you have a smart compiler, or because you got lucky.

Comment: Is NULL not same as '\0'? What I understand is that 

NULL == '\0' == 0x0.

Is is incorrect?

Comment: Usually NULL is ((void*)0)... though the values are equal, the types are different.

Comment: Nitpick - the first comparison is actually OK - `'\0'` is an integer value of zero, and in this context is evaluated as a null pointer constant.  It's not a good idea though, because it conveys a sense of confusion on the part of the author.  If you mean `NULL`, say `NULL`.

Comment: @caf exactly what i just wanted to write, +1. @Chris, and note that in C, character literals actually have type `int` not `char` (but this wouldn't change its ability to be a null pointer constant - `char` is an integer type too). Fix it and i will +1 u too xD

Comment: @litb - Is there any situation where assuming that a character literal is of type `char` instead of `int` will cause a programming error?

Comment: @Chris, dunno of a real example. But there are theoretical ones... :) A platform where char and int both have 16bits, and where char is unsigned. As a consequence, char would be promoted to unsigned int. Then, `'\0'-1` would become `UINT_MAX` if character constants had type `char`, and it would become `-1` if character constants had type int. (because int is not promoted). And then of course there is still the `sizeof` matter, which will probably give you a different result on most platforms.

Comment: I thought unadorned `char` was guaranteed to be signed. Is that not the case?

Comment: No, that's not the case. `char` is either unsigned or signed. The choice is implementation defined, and what's also important: It's still a distinct type (it's neither signed char, nor unsigned char) :)

Comment: Ah. I need to read up on my standards-fu. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 8):

According to the C99 spec,

- `NULL` expands to a null pointer constant, which is not required to be, but typically is of type `void *`
- `'\0'` is a character constant; character constants are of type `int`, so it's equivalen to plain `0`
- `"\0"` is a null-terminated string literal and equivalent to the compound literal `(char [2]){ 0, 0 }`

`NULL`, `'\0'` and `0` are all null pointer constants, so they'll all yield null pointers on conversion, whereas `"\0"` yields a non-null `char *` (which should be treated as `const` as modification is undefined); as this pointer may be different for each occurence of the literal, it can't be used as sentinel value.

Although you may use any integer constant expression of value `0` as a null pointer constant (eg `'\0'` or `sizeof foo - sizeof foo + (int)0.0`), you should use `NULL` to make your intentions clear.

Comment: Although to be *really* nit picking, `NULL` is expanded to a null pointer only in case it's defined as `(void*)0` (in which case it's both that and a null pointer constant) :) If it happens to be `0` or similar, then it's only a null pointer constant, which yet has to be converted to a null pointer :)

Comment: @litb: actually, `'\0'` might not be a valid null pointer constant as it's a character constant (C99 6.4.4.4) and not an integer constant (C99 6.4.4.1); character constants are sometimes called integer character constants, but does that make them an "integer constant expression" as required by C99 6.3.2.3?

Comment: @litb: thx - don't know why I did not search for the term myself

Answer (score 6):

Of these two, the first one is a type mistake: '\0' is a character, not a pointer. The compiler still accepts it because it can convert it to a pointer.

The second one "works" only by coincidence. "\0" is a string literal of two characters. If those occur in multiple places in the source file, the compiler may, but need not, make them identical.

So the proper way to write the first one is

```
char* array[] = { "abc", "def", NULL };
```

and you test for `array[index]==NULL`. The proper way to test for the second one is
`array[index][0]=='\0'`; you may also drop the '\0' in the string (i.e. spell it as `""`) since that will already include a null byte.

Comment: I do find it interesting that this problem has two answers that work, but neither is technically correct, and neither works for the reason the OP thinks they do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically `'\0'` is a character while `"\0"` is a string, so if you're checking for the null termination character the former is correct. However, as [Chris Lutz points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483232/array-of-char-should-end-at-0-or-0/1483248#1483248), your comparison won't work in it's current form.

Comment: Using `'\0'` is comparing a `char *` to a `char` which is like comparing apples to oranges. Neither is correct, really.

Comment: @Chris: <nitpick>using `'\0'` is comparing a `char *` to an `int`</nitpick>

Comment: @Christoph - that's what Chris Lutz pointed out. Rather than update my answer I pointed my answer at his

Answer (score 0):

The termination of an array of characters with a null character is just a convention that is specifically for strings in C. You are dealing with something completely different -- an array of character pointers -- so it really has no relation to the convention for C strings. Sure, you could choose to terminate it with a null pointer; that perhaps could be your convention for arrays of pointers. There are other ways to do it. You can't ask people how it "should" work, because you're assuming some convention that isn't there.

Comment: The convention is there for variable-length arrays: use NULL as sentinel value.

Answer (score 0):

Null termination is a bad design pattern best left in the history books.  There's still plenty of inertia behind c-strings, so it can't be avoided there.  But there's no reason to use it in the OP's example.

Don't use any terminator, and use sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) to get the number of elements.

Comment: +1 for sizeof array/sizeof array[ 0 ]. But do you think it is good enough reason for not using terminator?

Comment: this only works if the array is declared in-scope -- if it's passed by pointer then you cannot do `sizeof(array)` and you can only get the length by passing the size via a parameter, or searching for the null terminator.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  Pass the number of elements around along-side your array.  Safer and more clear than using a terminator.