# How do you write a while loop so that an entire file is read, rather than just one line?

Tags: c, file, stack

I have partially written code that scans in a file full of mathematical expressions in postfix and displays the number to the screen.

While it performs the computation, it will only read in one line and then exit. How do I modify the code to test all arithmetic expressions in the text file?

I've tried commanding the code to exit when `EOF`, `NULL` and `'\0'` are reached, but they all exit at one line.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int top = -1;
float stack[500];

/* push the given data into the stack */
void push (int data) {
    stack[++top] = data;
}

/* Pop the top element from the stack */
float pop () {
    float data;
    if (top == -1)
        return -1;
    data = stack[top];
    stack[top] = 0;
    top--;
    return (data);
}

int main() {

    char str[500];
    FILE *p;
    if((p=fopen("testfile1.txt","r"))==NULL){
        printf("\n Unable to open file string.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(str,500,p)!='\0'){

        float data = -1, operand1, operand2, result;

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
            if (isdigit(str[i])) {
                /*
                 * if the i/p char is digit, parse
                 * character by character to get
                 * complete operand
                 */
                data = (data == -1) ? 0 : data;
                data = (data * 10) + (str[i] - 48);
                continue;
            }

            if (data != -1) {
                /* if the i/p is operand, push it into the stack */
                push(data);
            }

            if (str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-'
                    || str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '/') {
                /*
                 * if the i/p is an operator, pop 2 elements
                 * from the stack and apply the operator
                 */
                operand2 = pop();
                operand1 = pop();
                if (operand1 == -1 || operand2 == -1)
                    break;
                switch (str[i]) {
                    case '+':
                        result = operand1 + operand2;
                        /* push the result into the stack */
                        push(result);
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        result = operand1 - operand2;
                        push(result);
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        result = operand1 * operand2;
                        push(result);
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        result = operand1 / operand2;
                        push(result);
                        break;
                }
            }
            data = -1;
        }
        if (top == 0)
            printf("Output:%3.2f\n", stack[top]);
        else
            printf("have given wrong postfix expression\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Also, the equations I need to read in are:

```
13 1 - 2 / 3 155 + *
100 100 100 100 + + +
10.33 2 2 2 2 2 * * * * *
30 10 - 10 - 10 - 2 *
300 13.25 - 11 3 - / 4 5 - * 3 /
```

It works for the first equation only. What can I do in terms of loop structure to make it read all of these equations out of the text file?

Comment: Note that `fgets()` returns a `char *`, and while it _is_ syntactically valid, it is definitely aconventional to write `'\0'` as a null pointer constant.  Use `0` or `NULL`.

Comment: Yes, was just about to add that. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483232/array-of-char-should-end-at-0-or-0 for more information on what Jonathan meant. Also, can you show the contents of the text file?

Comment: You could also submit the above code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com, since it contains several other mistakes.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Code Review is for reviewing/improving working code, not for fixing non-working code.

Answer (score 4):

Your `while` loop ends:

```
    return 1;
}
```

This means it returns from the function after reading the first line of input.

The most plausible fix is to remove the `return 1;` altogether.  An alternative might be:

```
    if (top == 0)
        printf("Output:%3.2f\n", stack[top]);
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "have given wrong postfix expression\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

However, exiting from an interactive calculator on the first mistake is a bit draconian. (It exits the program since the `return` is leaving `main()`.)  Note that errors should usually be reported on stderr.  It might be a good idea to echo the faulty expression too:

```
fprintf(stderr, "have given wrong postfix expression (%s)\n", str);
```

Comment: Thank you. This partially fixed it. It is now evaluating all lines, but returns "have given wrong postfix expression" for every expression after the first line.

There are no errors in the other expressions so I'm not sure what it won't properly evaluate them.

Comment: Well, fixing other problems is a separate exercise — this addresses the headline problem of the loop stopping after the first iteration.  Fixing the other problems is now a routine exercise for your debugging skills.  Add some print statements so you know what's going on.  Note that the `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)` loop is a bad idea; `strlen()` scans the whole line each time round the loop, making it into a quadratic algorithm.  Granted, your actual lines are short enough it won't hurt too much, but if your lines were nearly 500 characters long, it might start being measurable.

Comment: I've made the changes. Also, the headline problem is not entirely fixed because this code can evaluate all expressions correctly, but only evaluates the first line before returning errors for the other 4. As far as I've tested, no matter what line is placed first, it will be returned correctly, and others will bring error.

Comment: The problem is that you push the final result on the stack (because you don't know it is the final result), but you don't pop it off the stack at the end, so the stack gradually grows, and `top` isn't zero after the first loop.  So, you need to use: `printf("Output: %6.2f\n", pop());` to clear the stack after evaluating each expression.  I got there by (a) printing the value of `top` in the error statement, and (b) your comment about "it doesn't matter which line is processed first". You need to clear the stack after an error, or before the start of processing for each line (set `top = -1`).

Comment: Also, your numeric scanner doesn't recognize decimal points so the third line with `10.33` in the data detects end-of-number on the dot, and then has one number too many in the input for the number of operators (it treats `10.33` as numbers `10` and `33`).  You might want to look at [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html)
as a way of converting numbers to `double` (or `float`); its merit over `atof()` is that it tells you where the conversion ended.

Answer (score 3):

The code looks ok, but you have a `return` statement inside the `for` loop. This `return` statement will leave the whole `main` function.